# Editing PATH for Java

Tags: java, linux, manjaro

I am using Manjaro GNU/Linux 5.7.0-3 x86_64 and had installed older Java Oracle jdk1.8 previously but now I want to install Oracle jdk14.0.1 which I have unpacked to */opt*.

In order to reflect the changes, I edited *~/.bashrc* file by adding this line:

```
export PATH="/home/arjun/anaconda3/condabin:/home/arjun/.local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/opt/jdk-14.0.1/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/default/bin:/usr/bin/site_perl:/usr/bin/vendor_perl:/usr/bin/core_perl"
```

Then executed these to reload the terminal:

```
source ~/.bashrc
bash;
```

And I even restarted the computer but still, Java is using the older version:

```
$ javac -version
javac 1.8.0_252
```

What's going wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: I think the answer to this is highly dependent on the linux distribution that you are using. If I remember correctly on Ubuntu the command was `update-alternatives`, but I think you'd better ask in one of the linux sites if you don't get a working solution here.

Comment: FWIW, `java` usually is in `/usr/bin`, which comes first in your PATH

Answer (score 1):

In ArchLinux and manjaro you can use pre-installed `archlinux-java` utility.

for getting information about all installed java's and current choice, you need `status` and for change it you can use `set`

```sh
sudo archlinux-java status
sudo archlinux-java set java-14-jdk # or something similar related to java14
```

read more about it in the [wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Java)

Comment: The problem is JDK-14 is not showing up in `archlinux-java status` which shows `java-8-openjdk (default)` as the only output. `archlinux-java` will not let me set an invalid Java environment which I don't know how to fix?

Answer (score 0):

Because of different versions of java are installed, you can change default option with this command.

```
sudo update-alternatives --config java
```

With this command, you can select java version as default option.

Comment: `update-alternatives` is for the GNU/Linux distros such as debian, ubuntu and dpkg. I think that it's not applicable for Arch/Manjaro based Linux distros.